# External Javascript file not working, Help Needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, debugging

So I have an external javascript file. it is linked to my html code, however none of my code is taking effect, and i don't seem to be able to locate the problem.
Here is the external javascript file

```
function inputFocus(element)
{
  element.background="#FFFF00";
}
function showTick(containerId, imgId)
{
  document.getElementById(imgId).src="./images/tick/tick5.png";
  document.getElementById(containerId).style.visibility="visible";
}
function showX(containerId, imgId)
{
  document.getElementById(imgId).src="./images/x/x1.png";
  document.getElementById(containerId).style.visibility="visible";
}
function highlightValid(element, containerId, imgId)
{
  element.borderColor="#007A00";
  element.borderWidth="2px";
  showTick(containerId, imgId);
}
function highlightInvalid(element, containerId, imgId)
{
   element.borderColor="red";
   element.background="#FF4D4D";
   showX(containerId, imgId);
}
function validateName(element, containerId, imgId)
{
   document.getElementById(containerId).style.visibility="hidden";
   if(element.value==null || element.value=="")
   {
      highlightInvalid(element, containerId, imgId);
   }
   else
   {
      highlightValid(element, containerId, imgId);
   }
}
function validateEmail(element, containerId, imgId)
{
   document.getElementById(containerId).style.visibility="hidden";
   var atpos=element.value.indexOf("@");
   var dotpos=element.value.lastIndexOf(".");
   if(atpos<1||dotpos<=atpos+2||dotpos+2>=element.value.length)
   {
        highlightInvalid(element, containerId, imgId);
   }
   else
   {
        highlightValid(element, containerId, imgId);
   }
}
function getCurrentDate()
{
   var date=new Date();
   var day=date.getDate();
   var month=date.getMonth()+1; 
   var year=date.getYear();
   if (day<10)
   {
    day="0"+day;
   }
   if(month<10)
   {
     month="0"+month;
   }
   date = year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
   return date;
}
function validateDate(element, containerId, imgId)
{
  document.getElementById(containerId).style.visibility="hidden";
  if(element.value<getCurrentDate() || element.value==null || element.value=="")
  {
        highlightInvalid(element, containerId, imgId);
  }
  else
  {
        highlightValid(element, containerId, imgId);
  }
}
function validateAge(element, containerId, imgId)
{
    document.getElementById(containerId).style.visibility="hidden";
    if(isNaN(element.value) || element.value<1)
    {
     highlightInvalid(element, containerId, imgId);
    }
   else
   { 
     highlightValid(element, containerId, imgId);
   }
}
```

Even the very simple inputFocus function which is triggered with the onfocus event trigger.

Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TOD - TRUTH</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {} div.mainDiv {
      position: fixed;
      background: "#FFFFFF";
      width: 60%;
      border-style: dotted;
      border-radius: 15px;
      border-width: 1px;
      padding: 10px;
      top: 8%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -30%;
    }
    label.personalInfo {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      width: 175px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    input.non-radio {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }
    label.radioLabels {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
    }
    input.roundedInput {
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
    span.validationChecks {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div name="mainDiv" id="mainDiv" class="mainDiv">
    <form>
      <p align="center">
        <img src="./" alt="truth">
      </p>
      <label for="fullName" class="personalInfo">Full Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" class="non-radio roundedInput" placeholder="John Doe" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="validateName(this, nameSpan, nameImg)" required/><span id="nameSpan" class="validationChecks"><img src="" id="nameImg"/></span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <label for="yEmail" class="personalInfo">Your Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="yEmail" id="yEmail" class="non-radio roundedInput" placeholder="example@emailprovider.com" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="validateEmail(this, mEmailSpanSpan, mEmaIImg)" required/><span id="mEmailSpan" class="validationChecks"><img src="" id="mEmailImg"/></span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <label for="age" class="personalInfo">Your Age:</label>
      <input type="number" name="age" id="age" class="non-radio roundedInput" placeholder="e.g. 13" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="validateAge(this, ageSpan, ageImg)" max="150" required/><span id="ageSpan" class="validationChecks"><img src="" id="ageImg"/></span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <label for="sex" class="personalInfo">Are you male or female:</label>
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" class="radioLabels" value="male" required/>M &nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="sex" id="sex" class="radioLabels" value="female" required/>F
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <label for="rEmail" class="personalInfo">Recipient's Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="rEmail" id="rEmail" class="non-radio roundedInput" placeholder="example@emailprovider" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="validateEmail(this, rEmailSpan, rEmailImg)" required/><span id="rEmailSpan" class="validationChecks"><img src="" id="rEmailImg"/></span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <label for="date" class="personalInfo">Date to send question:</label>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="non-radio" min="2014-11-01" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="validateDate(this, dateSpan, dateImg)" required/><span id="dateSpan" class="validationChecks"><img src="" id="dateImg"/></span>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <hr/>
      <br/>
      <p align="left" name="questionsInstructions">Select <b>ONE</b> of the following questions to send.</p>
      <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="question" id="question" value="1" />
      <label for="q" class="radioLabels">Have you ever repeated a grade level? &nbsp;</label>
      <input type="radio" name="question" id="question" value="2" />
      <label for="q" class="radioLabels">Did you skip your last class? &nbsp;</label>
      <input type="radio" name="question" id="question" value="3" />
      <label for="q" class="radioLabels">Can you drive a car? &nbsp;</label>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <input type="radio" name="question" id="question" value="4" />
      <label for="q" class="radioLabels">Do watch anime? &nbsp;</label>
      <input type="radio" name="question" id="question" value="5" />
      <label for="q" class="radioLabels">Did you vote for Portia? &nbsp;</label>
      <input type="radio" name="question" id="question" value="6" />
      <label for="q" class="radioLabels">Did you enter your real name and age? &nbsp;</label>
      <br/>
      <hr/>
      <br/>
      <p name="pOfSubmit" id="pOfSubmit" align="center">
        <input type="image" src="./images/button.png" alt="Submit Form" />
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p align="center">&copy; Emile Keith - 1400282</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where did you include the file? make sure that it has correct file path.

Comment: Can create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @VenkataPanga , they were defined in that file, but i guess you'll want to see the html, as well. I'll edit the question to show the html.

Comment: Make sure that `javascript.js` is rendered properly, is this file located in the same folder where the parent html file exist. Also check browser-console for errors. As Ben said , Correct this line `if(element.value<getCurrentDate() || element.value==null || element.value=="")`

Comment: @venkataPanga yeah i fixed that line specifically, and both the files are in the same folder. The value of the src used in the script tag is "./javascript.js", so that checks out.

Comment: I'm seeing `src="javascript.js"`. if it renders then, in above code add `alert("I'm in inputFocus")` in `function inputFocus(){}` and then check.

Comment: @VenkataPanga , I places one alert before and after `code`element.background="#FFFF00"; `code` and both alerts appeared. However the colour of the background did not change. Could it be that passing the element with this to the function is not working?

Comment: Awesome ... file is good. now its background property issue., I'm adding answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change function like below, `background`, `borderWidth`... are style properties,  you missed to add `style`

```
function inputFocus(element)
{
  element.style.background="#FFFF00";
}
```

The same thing applies to all other missing places.

Check the same in other functions as well
`highlightValid`,  `highlightInvalid`

In HTML at event handler call you should make sure that you're sending params with right syntax.
Let us take one element for learning:

```
  <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" 
         class="non-radio roundedInput" placeholder="John Doe" 
         onfocus="inputFocus(this)" 
         onblur="validateName(this, nameSpan, nameImg)" required/>
```

at function call validateName(this, nameSpan, nameImg)
**param#1:** `this` refers the instance of current element.
**param#2:** `nameSpan` should be string we should include them in quotes like `'nameSpan'`, if we didn't include in quotes JS engine consider it as javascript `var` that defined some-where else, as a result it will throw you error.
**param#3:** also similar to #2.

So you have to correct the above element as below:

```
  <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" 
         class="non-radio roundedInput" placeholder="John Doe" 
         onfocus="inputFocus(this)" 
         onblur="validateName(this, 'nameSpan', 'nameImg')" required/>
```

Please correct all in the same way, hope you understand!

Comment: wow, Thanks a bunch, sometimes, you miss some simple things. Anyway that was only a partial solution to the problem. As you can see the tick or x that is to appear beside the input field is still not working.

Comment: there are lot of errors in your html to correct, updating answer by including... it seems you need more learning on standards and debugging.

Comment: yeah I just recently started learning web programming a few weeks ago. Though it is very much the same as c++, it is  still gives me a different feel. But I seriously need the help. Anyway I think I should at least try to give the rest of it another shot. So I am gonna give you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your Javascript file. All you need to do is navigate to http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php and paste your code in, then hit `lint`. The error is on line 73: `SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side`. Any significant Javascript error will cause your code to fail silently.

Comment: Thanks alot, i used the site until i got no more errors, in the javascript, and it still does not take effect. However i'll check my html in the site and see if that changes anything.

Comment: yeah i ran the css, and html, and got no errors. So my logic checks out.